# How do I obtain the current icon theme?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qt5.13

How can I obtain the current system icon theme in a Qt application? I tried [`QIcon::themeName`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qicon.html#themeName), but it just returns an empty string. (But [`QIcon::fallbackThemeName`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qicon.html#fallbackThemeName) works?!) Is there some "special trick" to using this method I am missing, or some other way to obtain the current theme name?

Possibly related to [this](/questions/28779868), but none of the answers there seem viable. (Edit: Okay, one of the methods there *does* work... after I fix the OP's typos . However, I'd prefer not relying on a Gnome-specific technique or needing to execute an external process.)

Comment: what is your desktop manager?

Comment: An optimal answer would be desktop-agnostic. Qt must know how to get the theme regardless of desktop environment, since AFAIK icons work on all (XDG-ish) desktop environments.

Comment: No, Qt does not support all desktop managers, and if your desktop manager is not supported then `QIcon::themeName()` returns an empty string as is your case.Read the docs: *On X11, the current icon theme depends on your desktop settings. **On other platforms it is not set by default.***

Comment: Okay, all ***X11*** desktops *that Qt supports*, then. At least GTK and KDE. For this purpose, I don't care about macOS and Windows, hence the [tag:linux] tag and clarification that I am asking about "XDG-ish" desktops. In particular, loading themed icons works and uses the correct theme, so *somewhere* Qt knows...